# smart gwt ListGrid using hashmap

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Anyone know about implementation ListGrid in smartgwt that using hashmap.
I am using smart gwt 3.0 and looking for implementation ListGrid with hashmap ...
Now ListGrid use table as container for record

I try implement my own listgrid but its too complicated for me :/

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'using hashmap'?  You mean for each record?

You can easily convert a HashMap to a SmartGWT Record and then insert it into a listgrid.

```
            RecordList list = new RecordList();
            ListGrid listGrid = new ListGrid();
            listGrid.setData(list);

            Record record = new Record(hashMap);
            list.add(record);
```

Comment: NO. Now ListGrid using table see: `public void setData(ListGridRecord[] records) {
        setAttribute("data", records, true);
    }` but in my solution i need using hashmap as datastore for ListGrid

Comment: So you want a Map<String,Map<Object,String>> to represent a collection of primary key -> record data?

Comment: can i ask why you're doing this?

Comment: I am using emite library for chat. This library using hashMap to store all users in chat. So its be nice to hold that hashmap in LinkGrid because now i must duplicate all entry and hold that entry in hashMap and in table []

Comment: by table you mean an array.  and i'm guessing you think that if you had the hashmap as the backing store instead of an array, it would automatically update the listgrid for you?  i'm afraid not!